# CSS/HTML How to align these elements for a mobile view?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to align the above elements in their divs evenly horizontally. In the above i'm trying to get 'high' and 'low' aligned so they are not up against the progress bar and are inline vertically. The checkboxes are fine but I used 'float:right' for the date - not ideal as this bumped it upward a little.

My html

```
<div class="show-for-small-only">
            <div class="parents linkable">
            <%= check_box_tag "homework[id][]", homework.id, checked = false, class: "narrowtr" %>
            <%= link_to homeworks_engagement_view_item_path(:id => homework.id) do %>
                    <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile horizTranslate linkable" data-bar-length="<%= homework.average_interest * 100 / 5 %>"><div class="text-center"><%= homework.average_interest %></div></div>
                    <font size="1" class="linkable mobile-center"><%= homework.significance.sig_option %></font>&emsp;&ensp;
                    <font size="1" class="linkable mobile-right"><strong><%= formatted_date(homework.due)%></strong></font>
                </div>
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

My CSS:

```
.parents {
   border-bottom: 20px;
   background-color: white;
   top: 0px;
   margin:0px; 
   height: 60px; 
   padding: 15px 2px 2px 3px;    
   border-width: 2px;
   border-bottom-width:1px;
   border-bottom-color:Grey;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   width: 100%;
}

.linkable{
color: black;
}
```

Div for bar:

```
.progress-meter-interest-mobile{
  background-color: #FFD733;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Aligned date with float:right...

```
.mobile-right{
  float:right;
  margin-right: 2px;
}



.mobile-center{
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   margin-right: 6px;
   background-color: #EEE;
 }
```

.horizTranslate is just css animation for the bars.

It's the two middle elements i'm really stuck on - the bar and "high" and "low". I have tried display:inline and display:inline-block and playing around with different divs but can't seem to get it.

Any ideas? Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You can add some small margin bottom on this labels. This is the easiest way. You can also play with display: flex on parent element and put date on right by position: absolute.

Comment: @ula Thanks, appreciate that, the margin top and bottom solves vertical alignment in the divs but i'm looking to align the element that contains "high" and "low" away to the right of the bar and have them in line vertically in each div...if that makes sense?

Comment: You should use 'float: right' again and move labels elements after date element in html. Because first float item will be first on right. I hope you understand me :)

Comment: Thank you! ugh should have thought of that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you look for a table like layout, stay with your inline block and give them a width (and a minor markup change, where I swapped the `progress`/`text` tags)

*Note, the `font` element is deprecated so I replaced it with a `span`*

```css
.parents {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 2px 2px 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid Grey;
  width: 240px;
}
.linkable {
  color: black;
}
.progress-meter-interest-mobile {
  background-color: #FFD733;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.parents.linkable > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.progress-meter-interest-mobile.low {
  width: 30px;
}
.progress-meter-interest-mobile.high {
  width: 60px;
}
.parents.linkable > :nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
}
.parents.linkable > :nth-child(3) {
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.parents.linkable > :nth-child(4) {
  width: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-for-small-only">
  <div class="parents linkable">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile low">2</div>
    </div>
    <span class="linkable">Low</span>
    <span class="linkable">12/12/2016</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parents linkable">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile high">4</div>
    </div>
    <span class="linkable">High</span>
    <span class="linkable">12/12/2016</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course you can use `flexbox`, as suggested, though you still need to swap the markup to make the "meter" work properly as well as give each element a width so they align vertically.

```css
.parents {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 2px 2px 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid Grey;
  width: 240px;
}
.linkable {
  color: black;
}
.progress-meter-interest-mobile {
  background-color: #FFD733;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.parents.linkable {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.progress-meter-interest-mobile.low {
  width: 30px;
}
.progress-meter-interest-mobile.high {
  width: 60px;
}
.parents.linkable > :nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
}
.parents.linkable > :nth-child(3) {
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.parents.linkable > :nth-child(4) {
  width: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="show-for-small-only">
  <div class="parents linkable">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile low">2</div>
    </div>
    <span class="linkable">Low</span>
    <span class="linkable">12/12/2016</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parents linkable">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <div class="progress-meter-interest-mobile high">4</div>
    </div>
    <span class="linkable">High</span>
    <span class="linkable">12/12/2016</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check CSS Flexbox. It solved my issues quite a few times.
[Flexbox Doc](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) The following should help in your case

```
.container {
  align-items:stretch;
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is a quick and tidy solution. here's a working example https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/mgv9anwh/

Comment: But only when content has the same width.

Comment: @Ula it depends, Flexbox has a bunch of different options depending on what you are trying to achieve. If you specify a width for the Childs, they can be totally different widths.